# jQuery Reveal elements after hidden

Tags: jquery, dom

Can anyone help me to understand why the reveal button here is not doing it's job and revealing everything?

Also, if you have a better suggestion for a method to hide / reveal all but a few elements that would appreciated

My JSFiddle example is much easier to understand... http://jsfiddle.net/qp7HB/

```
$('#hide').click(function(){
    $('body > :not(#reveal)').not(this).hide();
    $("#test1").add(this).appendTo("body");    
});

$('#reveal').click(function(){
    $('body').show();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `body` was never hidden, only its children. Showing the parent of an element does not automatically show the element itself if it has been hidden explicitly. You can do:

```
$('#reveal').click(function(){
    $('body').children().show();
    // or  $('body > *').show();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qp7HB/1/)

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at the wrong block and thought the demo was the same as the OPs.

Comment: Guys any reason why this doesn't work  $('body').hide();
 $('#test1').show();

Comment: @SparrwHawk: Because now you are in the reverse situation. `body` is hidden, so none if its descendants can be visible, not even if you explicitly say so.

Comment: @SparrwHawk - Your approach using `body` is always going to be a bit flawed. You should select the elements you want to `.show()` and `.hide()`, and the `body` tag when `hidden` will show nothing on the page, regardless of what you've done to it's children.